# How to fix Property 'touched' does not exist on type 'string' in my .html file

Tags: javascript, html, angular

This is my file register.component.html. When i'm trying to compile my angular app it gives me the following errors. I think they are related.

```
   <section id="register" class="mb-5 mt-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 mx-auto">
        <div class="card_register">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
              <form #formRegister="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onAddUser()">
                <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Register</h1>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="isError">
                  {{msgError}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="email" required minlength="8">
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="email.touched && !email.valid">
                  <div *ngIf="email.errors.required">Email is required</div>
                  <div *ngIf="email.errors.minlength">Email must be at least 8 characters</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="password" required minlength="5"
                    maxlength="10">
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="password.touched && !password.valid">
                  <div *ngIf="password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
                  <div *ngIf="password.errors.minlength">Password must be at least 5 characters</div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <h5>Seleccionar image:</h5>
                  <input type="file" accept=".png, .jpg" (change)="onUpload($event)">
                </div>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div [style.visibility]="(uploadPercent == 0) ? 'hidden' : 'visible'" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-success"
                    role="progressbar" [style.width]="(uploadPercent | async) +'%'">

                    <!-- <span class="progressText" *ngIf="urlImage | async">
                      Ok!!</span> -->
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <input #imageUser type="hidden" [value]="urlImage | async">
                <button *ngIf="urlImage | async; else btnDisabled" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Registrar</button>
                <ng-template #btnDisabled>
                  <button type="submit" disabled=true class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block">Registrar</button>
                </ng-template>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <a routerLink="/user/login" class="form-control login-user">Tienes cuenta?</a>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook" (click)="onLoginFacebook()">
                    <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>
                    FACEBOOK
                  </button>
                  <button class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google" (click)="onLoginGoogle()">
                    <span class="fa fa-google"></span>
                    GOOGLE
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**ERROR in src\app\components\users\register\register.component.html(17,62): : Property 'touched' does not exist on type 'string'.
src\app\components\users\register\register.component.html(17,62): : Property 'valid' does not exist on type 'string'.
src\app\components\users\register\register.component.html(25,62): : Property 'touched' does not exist on type 'string'.
src\app\components\users\register\register.component.html(25,62): : Property 'valid' does not exist on type 'string'.
src\app\components\users\register\register.component.html(35,24): : This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'Observable' and 'number' have no overlap.**

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it replacing

```
public email: string = '';
```

by

```
public email;
```

in my register.component.ts

Answer (score -1):

```
to solve all the following errors when you run "ng build --prod":

ERROR in src / app / components / users / register / register.component.html (17,62): Property 'touched' does not exist on type 'string'.
src / app / components / users / register / register.component.html (17,62): Property 'valid' does not exist on type 'string'.
src / app / components / users / register / register.component.html (25,62): Property 'touched' does not exist on type 'string'.
src / app / components / users / register / register.component.html (25,62): Property 'valid' does not exist on type 'string'.
src / app / components / users / register / register.component.html (35,24): This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'Observable <number>' and '0' have no overlap.

    I had to modify the register.component.ts file like this:
  public email;
  public password;
  public touched;
  public valid;

then I modify the register.component.html file like this

 <div [style.visibility] = "(uploadPercent == [0])? 'hidden': 'visible'" class = "progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-success"
                    role = "progressbar" [style.width] = "(uploadPercent | async) + '%'">
```

[erreur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIi72.png)
[erreur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB7zF.png)

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFX8G.png)

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gRp3.png)

Comment: Please do not post the same answer twice

Answer (score -1):

I had to modify the register.component.ts file like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  isError: any;
  err: any;
  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService, private storage: AngularFireStorage) { }
  @ViewChild('imageUser', {static: true}) inputImageUser: ElementRef;

  public email = '';
  public password = '';



  uploadPercent: Observable<number>;
  urlImage: Observable<string>;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onUpload(e) {
    // console.log('subir', e.target.files[0]);
    const id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const filePath = `uploads/profile_${id}`;
    const ref = this.storage.ref(filePath);
    const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);
    this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
    task.snapshotChanges().pipe(finalize(() => this.urlImage = ref.getDownloadURL())).subscribe();
  }
  onAddUser() {
    this.authService.registerUser(this.email, this.password)
      .then((res) => {
        this.authService.isAuth().subscribe(user => {
          if (user) {
            user.updateProfile({
              displayName: '',
              photoURL: this.inputImageUser.nativeElement.value
            }).then(() => {
              this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
            }).catch((error) => console.log('error', error));
          }
        });
      }).catch(err => console.log('err', err.message));
  }
  onLoginGoogle(): void {
    this.authService.loginGoogleUser()
      .then((res) => {
        this.onLoginRedirect();
      }).catch(err => console.log('err', err.message));
  }
  onLoginFacebook(): void {
    this.authService.loginFacebookUser()
      .then((res) => {
        this.onLoginRedirect();
      }).catch(err => console.log('err', err.message));
  }

  onLoginRedirect(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
  }

}
```

I modified the register.component.html file like this:

```
<section id="register" class="mb-5 mt-5">
  <div class="container" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 mx-auto">
        <div class="card_register">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
              <form #formRegister="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onAddUser()">
                <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Register</h1>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="isError">
                  {{msgError}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="email" required minlength="8">
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="email['touched'] && !email['valid']">
                  <div *ngIf="email.errors.required">Email is required</div>
                  <div *ngIf="email.errors.minlength">Email must be at least 8 characters</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="password" required minlength="5"
                    maxlength="10">
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" *ngIf="password['touched'] && !password['valid']">
                  <div *ngIf="password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
                  <div *ngIf="password.errors.minlength">Password must be at least 5 characters</div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="form-group" style="width: auto">
                <h5>Selectionner image:</h5>
                  <input type="file" accept=".png, .jpg" (change)="onUpload($event)">
                </div>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div [style.visibility]="(uploadPercent == [0]) ? 'hidden' : 'visible'" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-success"
                    role="progressbar" [style.width]="(uploadPercent | async) +'%'">

                    <!-- <span class="progressText" *ngIf="urlImage | async">
                      Ok!!</span> -->
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <input #imageUser type="hidden" [value]="urlImage | async">
                <button *ngIf="urlImage | async; else btnDisabled" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Register</button>
                <ng-template #btnDisabled>
                  <button type="submit" disabled=true class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block">Register</button>
                </ng-template>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <a routerLink="/user/login" class="form-control login-user">Do you have account?</a>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook" (click)="onLoginFacebook()">
                    <!-- <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span> -->
                    FACEBOOK
                  </button>
                  <button class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google" (click)="onLoginGoogle()">
                    <!-- <span class="fa fa-google"></span> -->
                    GOOGLE
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```